# C# Web Reference - ArrayOfString not serialising

Tags: c#, magento, soap

I am using Web References in C# to interface with Magento, which uses a SOAP API. The WSDL contains lots of definitions as you can imagine, but I'm having a problem with this particular one:

```
<complexType name="ArrayOfString">
<complexContent>
<restriction base="soapenc:Array">
<attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[]"/>
</restriction>
</complexContent>
</complexType>
```

Any propertes of a method that are an ArrayOfString are being brought back to my code as string[], which is fine, but when serialising it *back* to Magento it's serialising it as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:Magento" xmlns:types="urn:Magento/encodedTypes" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <tns:catalogProductCreate>
            <sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</sessionId>
            <type xsi:type="xsd:string">simple</type>
            <set xsi:type="xsd:string">63</set>
            <sku xsi:type="xsd:string">CHRISTEST</sku>
            <productData href="#id1" />
        </tns:catalogProductCreate>
        <tns:catalogProductCreateEntity id="id1" xsi:type="tns:catalogProductCreateEntity">
            <categories href="#id2" />
            <websites href="#id3" />
            <name xsi:type="xsd:string">Chris Test 8</name>
            <description xsi:type="xsd:string">fsd</description>
            <short_description xsi:type="xsd:string">Chris Test 8</short_description>
            <weight xsi:type="xsd:string">0.0000</weight>
            <status xsi:type="xsd:string">1</status>
            <visibility xsi:type="xsd:string">1</visibility>
            <category_ids href="#id4" />
            <website_ids href="#id5" />
            <price xsi:type="xsd:string">0.00000</price>
            <tax_class_id xsi:type="xsd:string">4</tax_class_id>
            <tier_price href="#id6" />
        </tns:catalogProductCreateEntity>
        <soapenc:Array id="id2" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[0]" />
        <soapenc:Array id="id3" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[0]" />
        <soapenc:Array id="id4" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[1]">
            <Item>35</Item>
        </soapenc:Array>
        <soapenc:Array id="id5" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[1]">
            <Item>1</Item>
        </soapenc:Array>
        <soapenc:Array id="id6" soapenc:arrayType="tns:catalogProductTierPriceEntity[0]" />
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And this is resulting in the arrays being ignored. I believe the reason the ArrayOfString entity isn't being added to my service model is because it has a 'restriction', but I'm going to need this to get the data back to Magento. Any ideas guys?